# can't read docx file as same as using php

Tags: php, ms-word, docx

I am trying to read docx file using below code, this is working fine but my docx file has bold, headings and etc, but below code is not showing as same as word document.

[demo docx file](https://www.reqsbook.com/resumes/testing.docx)

```
function read_file_docx($filename){

$striped_content = '';
$content = '';

if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;

$zip = zip_open($filename);

if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);

    //echo $content;
    //echo "<hr>";
    //file_put_contents('1.xml', $content);

    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}
$filename = "testing.docx";// or /var/www/html/file.docx

$content = read_file_docx($filename);
if($content !== false) {

    $viewResume = nl2br($content);

    $str = $viewResume;
    $keyword = 'When';
    $str = preg_replace("/\b([a-z]*${keyword}[a-z]*)\b/i","<b style='color:#F00;'>$1</b>",$str);
    echo "$str"; 
    echo preg_match_all('([^\.\!\?]+)',$str,$keyword);


}
else {
    echo 'Couldn\'t the file. Please check that file.';
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this code _would_ display any formatting?

Comment: it is showing running content like below....New changes 
Please check that why we can login as a client with the staff id and password. done
In the below image you can see that I just login as a client with the staff login details.

Search option is not working and as well as its not showing the details as we want to search. done
Search can be done with the name, contact number, email ID, client ID and in all the status. Need bit time
Without comments staff should not be able to update the status. Done 
When I update the client from the staff I am not taken to the same field

Comment: Okay, next question. Did you write this code? If not, do you at least have some understanding of how it works?

Comment: I have writen the above code and I don't have idea how it is working, I am new to PHP. Please help me

Comment: Parsing Office document formats is not a good starter task when learning PHP.

Answer (score 1):

docx is a zipped file format, so you can unzip it by yourself using a simple unzipper.

In there, your main text is in word/document.xml

The elements have

- `<w:p>` : paragraphs
- `<w:r>` : runs (which contain styles)
- `<w:t>` : which contain text

In your current solution, you are just retrieving the text (which is inside the `<w:t>`. To be able to get the style, you would need to parse the `<w:t>`. For example `<w:u w:val=\"single\"/>` means underlined.

However, this may become quite complex, so what I suggest is to use a already made solution such as [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/demos.html).